# Problems regarding calling af sub in a function

Tags: vba, function

I have been Googling alot, but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
    Public Sub ConnectToBloomberg(Code)

Dim sUrl As String
Dim rawJson As Dictionary
Dim pricedata As Object
Dim dataRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

sUrl = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & Code & "?timeFrame=1_YEAR"

Set dataRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

With dataRequest
    .Open "GET", sUrl, True
    .Send
    .WaitForResponse
    FetchedData = .ResponseText
End With

 FetchedData = Right(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)
 FetchedData = Left(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)

Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(FetchedData)

Set pricedata = Json.Item("price")

End Sub

Function MEANVALUE() As Double

ConnectToBloomberg (Code)

For Each Item In pricedata

    Count = Count + 1

    YReturn = Item("value") - LastPrice

    LastPrice = Item("value")

    Total = Total + YReturn

Next

Mean = Total / Count

MEANVALUE = Mean

End Function
```

The problem should be in the second function, where I try to call the Sub.

I am pretty noobie to VBA! :-)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

To explain in an another way. This code actually works:

```
    Function MEANVALUE(Code) As Double

Dim sUrl As String
Dim rawJson As Dictionary
Dim pricedata As Object
Dim dataRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

sUrl = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & Code & "?timeFrame=1_YEAR"

Set dataRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

With dataRequest
    .Open "GET", sUrl, True
    .Send
    .WaitForResponse
    FetchedData = .ResponseText
End With

 FetchedData = Right(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)
 FetchedData = Left(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)

Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(FetchedData)

Set pricedata = Json.Item("price")

For Each Item In pricedata

    Count = Count + 1

    YReturn = Item("value") - LastPrice

    LastPrice = Item("value")

    Total = Total + YReturn

Next

Mean = Total / Count

MEANVALUE = Mean

End Function
```

But I am using this code in other functions:

```
Dim sUrl As String
Dim rawJson As Dictionary
Dim pricedata As Object
Dim dataRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

sUrl = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & Code & "?timeFrame=1_YEAR"

Set dataRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

With dataRequest
    .Open "GET", sUrl, True
    .Send
    .WaitForResponse
    FetchedData = .ResponseText
End With

 FetchedData = Right(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)
 FetchedData = Left(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)

Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(FetchedData)

Set pricedata = Json.Item("price")
```

So I want to be able to call it, instead of using the code manually in each function.

Comment: (a) What code are you using to call the Function, or is it a UDF?  (b) In the Function you are using a variable `Code` that you have never assigned a value to.  You are also using a variable called `pricedata` that you have never assigned a value to.  (c) Your Sub is doing a lot of work, but not actually doing anything with the results of that work - just assigns it to some temporary values and then finishes.  (Perhaps you meant those temporary variables to be passed back to the Function that called the Sub?)

Comment: (d) Did you really intend to tag this question with the "su" tag?

Comment: I am calling the function in the Workbook =MEANVALUE(C3).
The function actually worked before when I just added the code from sub procedure into til function manually, but I am using that code many times, så I just want to be able to call.

Comment: Your function does not accept a parameter, so you shouldn't be passing one.  Or was it meant to be passed a parameter `Code As String`?

Comment: No, the su should have been sub :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your current `ConnectToBloomberg` subroutine isn't actually doing anything productive.  All the calculations it does are lost at the end of the subroutine.

You have several ways to fix this:

1. Make `pricedata` a module-level scoped variable, so that your `MEANVALUE` function can access it as well as your `ConnectToBloomberg` subroutine.
2. Pass `pricedata` back via a parameter in the call to `ConnectToBloomberg`
3. Change `ConnectToBloomberg` to be a `Function` (returning the price data) instead of a subroutine.

Below is some code using the third approach:

```
Public Function ConnectToBloomberg(Code As String) As Object

    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim rawJson As Dictionary
    Dim dataRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim Json As Object
    Dim FetchedData As String

    sUrl = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & Code & "?timeFrame=1_YEAR"

    Set dataRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    With dataRequest
        .Open "GET", sUrl, True
        .Send
        .WaitForResponse
        FetchedData = .ResponseText
    End With

    FetchedData = Right(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)
    FetchedData = Left(FetchedData, Len(FetchedData) - 1)

    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(FetchedData)

    Set ConnectToBloomberg = Json.Item("price")
End Sub

Function MEANVALUE(Code As String) As Double
    Dim pricedata As Object
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim YReturn As Double
    Dim LastPrice As Double
    Dim Total As Double

    Set pricedata = ConnectToBloomberg(Code)

    For Each Item In pricedata
        Count = Count + 1
        YReturn = Item("value") - LastPrice
        LastPrice = Item("value")
        Total = Total + YReturn
    Next
    If Count > 0 Then
        MEANVALUE = Total / Count
    Else
        MEANVALUE = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Okay! Thank you! Any reason you picked solution three?

Comment: @JacobKildetoftHenriksen Option 3 just seems to me to be the most intuitive way of thinking about the code when there is only one "thing" being returned from `ConnectToBloomberg`.  In my opinion a `Sub` does something, while a `Function` returns something.